# v-file-input shows 2 name when I upload a file

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using nuxt and recently I have found something.
[Pattern now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cP2ey.png)

Upper is the uploaded file name, and the below is the name of the target file.
I am gonna eliminate the below and replace it with the upper. Which means:
[Pattern expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MooQU.png)

Actually what I really want here is how to change my filename in input tag when I uploaded it.

Comment: can you show your code ?

Comment: <v-file-input
    :label="fileName"
    @change="submitFile"
    ref="file"
    v-model="file"
  ></v-file-input>

Answer (score 0):

Try this code below :

```
<v-file-input @change="submitFile" ref="file" v-model="file" ></v-file-input>
```

Just Remove your label , it will work according to what you want.

Comment: I already tried that.
But that doesn't show changed name but the original filename.
Which I don't want.